# Using cURL to download a web stream

Tags: bash, download, streaming, http, curl

I am trying to download a streaming audio feed, from an online radio station. **The station used to operate on a MP3 shoutcast feed, but now has upgraded to an AAC HTTP audio feed**.

I used to use "streamripper" in terminal to rip the station for my car rides, but **now streamripper fails to rip the new stream**. I'm pretty sure the station is utilizing http chunked transfer encoding now for their stream, which streamripper does not support.

I have come up with a new solution, where I isolated the audio feed from the station's web player, and **I am utilizing cURL to rip the feed into an audio file** I can take with me.

However **I am constantly getting "completions" on my cURL, when it should endlessly record**. I have even set the max time parameter to 43200s (12 hours), but I just end up with varying file sizes. Usually each resultant file is not longer than 1 hour. Sometimes it can be longer than an hour though. The file sizes and times are different. The file "breaks/completes" after a short period and I have to use a script to restart the cURL recording. I end up with a large folder of fractal recordings, when I should just have 2 recordings per day, (every 12 hours). When I look at the verbose of the cURL transfer, it just ends with "cURL connection left in tact". There is no error in the cURL log, therefore **I am not sure how I can force cURL to attempt to "reconnect" and keep parsing the stream into the same file, even though it thinks it's finished.**

**I have also tried using "wget" and "Jdownloader"**, They both have the same result, where it finishes after a short amount of time.

**I am not sure what I can do to essentially force a reconnect and keep downloading into the same file without overwriting it.**

What can I do to make sure my recordings don't "break"? Is there anything I can do to either force a reconnect? Or perhaps there is some way to tell cURL to wait even if the cURL transfer speed drops to 0?

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post a link to the main page or main stream URL for this station? Several modern HTTP-based streaming formats, such as HLS and DASH, are automatically posted in chunks rather than a single continuous file containing the whole program.

Comment: (http://zas4.ndx.co.za/proxy/bushradio?mp=/stream) is the URL to the direct audio feed. My recording durations vary, sometimes it is 10 minutes sometimes it is 3 hours. But I can never get a 12 hour file. If there is any information you can provide regarding the stream that would be great! I would love it if I can get a continuous feed without breaks.

Answer (score 2):

> how I can force cURL to attempt to "reconnect" and keep parsing the stream into the same file, even though it thinks it's finished

A general way (not specific to `curl`) is:

```
while true; do curl -o - … ; done >file
```

The point is `curl` writes to stdout. We redirect the entire loop to a file, no matter how many restarts it takes. This way the output from multiple consecutive `curl` processes is concatenated and goes to a single file.

To run this for 12 hours:

```
timeout 12h sh -c 'while true; do curl -o - … ; done >file'
```

To run non-stop and create a new file every 12 hours:

```
while true; do
   timeout 12h sh -c 'while true; do curl -o - … ; done >"audio_feed_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%T)"'
done
```

To start a new file on demand just kill the current `timeout` or `sh` that is its child.

---

Note I don't know if a stream with few seconds missing from time to time, yet concatenated, will result in a playable file. I expect protocols/containers/codecs designed to be streamed via network in real time to be able to re-synchronize after a missing fragment; this should work regardless if data comes from a server or a file. If the stream you want to capture is like this, then you will experience "missing content" while playing later (at timestamps when one `curl` exited and the next one hasn't taken over yet), but this "hiccup" should not stop a player that really knows how to handle such stream.

Comment: I currently use "cat" in terminal to join all my file parts into one file to take with me, and I just try to ignore gaps in the audio. Would the process you described not result in something similar? I already have a script that throws cURL into a loop and makes it endlessly run when it finishes. I do like your method because it skips the need for "cat", which is still very useful. But is there no way to salvage the connection in cURL somehow? Establishing a new connection creates too much of a gap. Perhaps I can make it download the stream in chunks instead, allowing more of a buffer?

Comment: @gunter Yes, my method is like `cat`, but it works on the fly. This way you don't waste time, disk space and disk operations to read few files and write one big file. At the moment I cannot help you with `curl` itself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion